# AJAX отправка формы не работает на IOS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Проблема **только на IOS Safari.**
Сайт https://ortomag77.ru/ (в разработке). На странице покупки не работает оформление заказа(через AJAX). Пробовал отключить кэширование, не помогло. Сразу скажу, что css-свойство cursor:pointer.

Comment: да и в обычном Safari macOS не работает

Comment: При нажатии на "оформить заказ" прилетает ответ: "пожалуйста выберете регион доставки" в success, но во-первых я все выбрал, во-вторых визуально на сайте я не вижу этой ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работает и в обычном Safari на Мак.
Поэтому можно отдебажить.

Бегло раставив брейкпоинты можно предположить ошибку в коде, когда после запроса `url: 'index.php?route=checkout/newstorecheckout/validate'` прилетает "ошибка"

[image: ответ от проверочного скрипта]

после этого исполняется код, где перебором вы ищете нужные поля и добавляете класс и меняете плейсхолдер.

[image: обработка ошибки]

Но в DOM нет ничего с `name=zone`, нашел вручную `name=zone_id`
А `zone_id` это select.

Ошибка видимо в этом, частично.

Но даже при этом, я заполнял поле Адрес, почему прилетает ошибка?